# send multiple same mail with powershell

Tags: powershell

Is possible to send multiple same mails with `powershell` for example 10 mails to same user ?
With follow script I can send just a mail .

```
$From ="user name"
$To = "user name"
$Subject = "Email Subject"
$Body = "hello"
$`SMTPServer` = "`smtp` name"
$`SMTPPort` = "`nrport`"
$BCC = "`username`"
Send-`MailMessage` -From $From -to $To  -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -`SmtpServer` $`SMTPServer`  -`UseSsl` -Bcc $BCC
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `for` loop to do something several times (10 in this case):

```
for ($i = 1; $i -le 10; $i++)
```

This is pretty general concept, not unique to powershell

Comment: True. But in PowerShell a more readable form would be `1..10 | foreach { "do something $_" }`

Comment: arguable, anyone familiar with programming of any kind will understand a `for` loop whereas `1..10`?

Comment: Seems pretty intuitive to me. Anyone familiar with the english language (which is a much larger group than people familiar with programming) can intuitively understand that expression.

Comment: its a matter of preference, no idea why you got mad over such a simple thing, you know you can edit answers? you can create your own?

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this

```
$From ="user name"
$To = "user name"
$SMTPServer = "smtp name"
$SMTPPort = "nrport"

$ListMailSubsject=@([pscustomobject]@{subject="subject1"; body="body1"}, [pscustomobject]@{subject="subject1"; body="body2"})

foreach ($MailSubsject in $ListMailSubsject)
{
   Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To  -Subject $MailSubsject.subject -Body $MailSubsject.body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer  -UseSsl -Bcc $BCC  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code. Try to use "[splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675931.aspx)". It makes the code more readable and cleaner.

```
1..10 | foreach-object {
    $mail = @{
        From ="user name"
        To = "user name"
        Subject = "Email Subject"
        Body = "hello"
        SMTPServer = "smtp name"
        SMTPPort = "port"
        BCC = "username"
        }
    Send-MailMessage @mail
}
```